# Question about diffeomorphisms of tungent bundles.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle, diffeomorphism

I'm studying the chapter one of this [text](https://www.ime.usp.br/~gorodski/teaching/mat5799-2019/master.pdf). In the end of the chapter there are a few exercises. The exercises 32 to 35 asks to constructs natural diffeomorphisms that maps fibers to fibers. The exercises are:

1. $TS^1 \approx S^1 \times \mathbb R$.
2. $T(M \times N) \approx TM \times TN$.
3. $T\mathbb{R}^n \approx \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$.
4. $TS^n \times \mathbb R \approx S^n \times \mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Where $TM$ denotes the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold $M$. I have no idea in how start to construct such diffeomorphisms. Can any one help me with at least one of this questions?

Thanks.

Comment: For 1, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193999/ts1-is-diffeomorphic-to-s1-times-mathbf-r).

Comment: The 4th seems really weird: isn’t the second $\approx$ a $\times$ instead? If so, consider the sum of $TS^n$ and of the “tautological bundle” on $S^n$, ie you associate to any $x$ the line $\mathbb{R}x$. For the simpler 3., just choose $n$ global sections $s_1, \ldots, s_n$ of $T\mathbb{R}^n$ that are a basis at each point and the morphism is $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\times \sum_{k=1}^n{y_ks_k(x)}$.